# Why i receive store object instead my own object (PizzaState)?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx-store

I am try to create a pizzas$ object in type `Observable<PizzaState>` but i get a problem

I receive a store object instead PizzaState object and i don't understand why and how to fix it

this the object i get

```
Store {_isScalar: false, actionsObserver: ActionsSubject, reducerManager: ReducerManager, source: Store, operator: DistinctUntilChangedOperator}
```

I only tried to read my `initialState` from my store

my read component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ProductesState } from '../shared/models/productesState.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { PizzaState } from '../shared/models/pizzaState.model';
import * as fromPizzas from '../store/actions/pizzas.action'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-read',
  templateUrl: './read.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./read.component.css']
})
export class ReadComponent implements OnInit {

  public pizzas$: Observable<PizzaState> = this.store.pipe(select('pizzas'));

  constructor(private store: Store<ProductesState>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.pizzas$);
  }
```

my actions

```
import { Action, createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Pizza } from 'src/app/shared/models/Pizza.model';


export const LoadPizzas = createAction('[Products] Load Pizzas')
export const LoadPizzasFail = createAction('[Products] Load Pizzas Fail', props<{ payload: Pizza[] }>())
export const LoadPizzasSuccess = createAction('[Products] Load Pizzas Success', props<{ payload: Pizza[] }>())
```

my reducer

```
import { PizzaState } from 'src/app/shared/models/pizzaState.model';
import * as fromPizzas from '../actions/pizzas.action'
import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';

export const initialState: PizzaState = {
    data: [],
    loaded: false,
    loading: false
}

export const reducer = createReducer<PizzaState>(
    initialState, on(
        fromPizzas.LoadPizzas, state => {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        }
    ), on(
        fromPizzas.LoadPizzasSuccess, state => {
            return {
                ...state,
                loaded: true,
                loading: false
            }
        }
    ), on(
        fromPizzas.LoadPizzasFail, state => {
            return {
                ...state,
                loaded: false,
                loading: false
            }
        }
    )

)
```

reducer.index

```
import { reducer } from './pizzas.reducer';
import { ActionReducerMap } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ProductesState } from 'src/app/shared/models/productesState.model';

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<ProductesState> = {
    pizzas: reducer
}
```

my module

```
import { reducers } from './store/reducers/index';

    StoreModule.forRoot({
      pizzas: reducers.pizzas
    })
```

my models

```
import { PizzaState } from './pizzaState.model';

export interface ProductesState {
    pizzas: PizzaState;
}

----------

import { Pizza } from './Pizza.model';

export interface PizzaState {
    data: Pizza[],
    loaded: boolean,
    loading: boolean
}

----------

export interface Pizza {
    id: number,
    name: string
}
```

if need more files i will glad to add ,
thank you for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are logging your Observable instead of subscribing to it. NGRX uses an extended Observable called Store, so what you are seeing is absolutely correct.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-read',
  templateUrl: './read.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./read.component.css']
})
export class ReadComponent implements OnInit {

  public pizzas$: Observable<PizzaState> = this.store.pipe(select('pizzas'));

  constructor(private store: Store<ProductesState>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.pizzas$);   // This logs your Observable, which holds your store value over time

    this.pizzas$.subscribe(currentPizzas => {
       // This function is called everytime your state changes + initial state
       console.log(currentPizzas); // This logs your current pizza state
    });
  }
}
```

Since you are refering [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4KtoqTNmEf8) over and over again, I'll explain the difference. In the video he is creating a Stream containing the `cars` in an Observable called `cars$`. He then uses that Observable only inside his template to show some data by using the `async` pipe like this `<car-table [cars]="cars$ | async">`. This `async` pipe takes care of subscribing and unsubscribing for you.

Comment: this is can't be because according of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4KtoqTNmEf8 34.16 min , he isn't subscribe and still receive all information from store moreover in another small application that i created this work for me without subscribe .

Comment: @LichayTiram You even typed it as an Observable... `public pizzas$: Observable<PizzaState>`. Also, in the video you can see that he uses the `async` pipe in his templates. Which does the subscribing/unsubscribing logic. Maybe try out my code and you will see that it works :)

Comment: yes it work because you use a subscribe function , i don't want use it inside video he isn't use any subscribe function only this `this.store.pipe(select(state => state.pizzas));`

Comment: @LichayTiram He is not using subscribe because he is using the `async` pipe in his template. `pipe` essentially is applied to one `Observable` and applies some functions to that Observable. In this case, the `select` function. It then returns another Observable containing your state stream. You cannot log any values from an Observable without subscribing somewhere, either by using `subscribe` directly, or using the `async` pipe in your template - but this calls `scubscribe` under the hood. You should probably look deeper into Observables before you use a State Management System like NGRX.

Comment: when i add this ```<div *ngIf="pizzas$ | async">
        <h2>{{pizzas$.loading}}</h2>
    </div>``` This isn't show only the first as Object object and i try it too                   `<h2 *ngIf="(pizzas$ | async)">{{pizzas$.loading}}</h2>`

Comment: The async pipe only subscribes inside the block it is used. You need to define the resulting value as a new variable or use async pipe every time. So either like this `<div *ngIf="pizzas$ | async as pizzas"> <h2>{{pizzas.loading}}</h2></div>` (this defines a variable pizzas with the result of the async pipe as value. Or like this: `<div *ngIf="pizzas$ | async"> <h2>{{(pizzas$ | async)?.loading}}</h2></div>`. This uses the async pipe on each block you need it.